# Enable only all fridays in calendar of magento for a specific product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, product, calendar

In a series of products i have select calendar option.

I want to set only friday enabled in calendar for specific product, not in all products having calendar.

Is there any possible way to do it.

will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there no solution for the above problem?

Comment: leave it, it is a waste of time to post here and visit every time. thanks.